# How is the random variable $X=\max\{x_1,\dots,x_n\}$ related to the negative binomial distribution

Tags: probability, negative-binomial

Consider a jar with $N$ indexed balls from $1$ to $N$ and the variable $X=\max\{x_1,\dots,x_n\} $ where $n<N$ is the number of balls we took out without replacement.

I found that $P(X=k)=\begin{cases} 0 &\text{ if } k<n\\ \frac{{k-1\choose n-1}}{N\choose n-1} &\text { if } n\le k\le N \end{cases}$

Is $X$  related to the negative binomial distribution, and how?

Comment: What are the $x_i$?

Comment: the balls we took out

Comment: Ah okay. I don’t see a connection with negative binomial, as the trials in a negative-binomial-type experiment are independent. The sampling without replacement makes the trials dependent (_e.g._ if you sample ball $N$ on the first go, $X$ becomes degenerate).

Comment: Since the sampling is without replacement, perhaps you should consider the relation to HyperGeometric distribution.